# ElasticSearch search has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch Rails and I'm trying to search through a has_many association.

I wanna do this: `article.comments.search(...).`

However, it's not scoping to comments of that specific `article`.

It's searching the entire `Comment` model, like this: `Comment.search(...)`

How do I scope this to a specific ActiveRecord `has_many` relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about the https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model gem, the scope doesn't really matter here.

You have to use a `filtered` query, and put use a filter on something on like `article_id`.

(There's a comprehensive example for associations here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/examples/activerecord_associations.rb)